# How to Pass values trow subreports and main report in ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have two subreports in a main report in ireport. There is separate totals in those sub reports. I just want to take total of that two sub total to the main report. (TO a text field). How can I do that. Am null in ireport.

Comment: You can look at the subreport sample: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/samples.html

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans goto Window->Pellete. in sub-report properties last property is `Return Values`.
In the *Return Values Dialog* box you can *map main report and sup reports variables*.

A variable in sub-report that hold the total should be map to the variable in main-report in which you want the

Comment: No one mentioned Netbeans here. Is this option in iReport?